# How to disable HTTPS and redirect HTTPS to HTTP in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

The client just wanted to test the site without pointing the domain to the new server. We just want to test the site in port80 (HTTP) only, since they haven't the purchased SSL yet.

So the website is set up at `http://<ip-address>` and we are using `ip` to test it.

But the problem is, all the themes (css/js files) are loaded over HTTPS. We need to disable it and load these files over HTTP only.

What I have tried so far that didn't work for me

1. htaccess

```
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{HTTP} !=on
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

2. _wp_options Table

[image]

3. wp-config.php

   `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);`

[image]

4. General Settings

[image]

But unfortunately this doesn't work.

The problem is all css are loaded in HTTPS but these files exists when you try them to search in browser using http

[image]

Comment: Have you changed the followings in wp_config ? define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_HOME',    'http://example.com' );

Comment: @Usman - yes did tried that but still the css files are loaded to https

Comment: @wp78de - My General settings and Site address are already http but still the css files are loaded in https

Comment: Please check my update

Comment: You may have to find the assets that are linked via https:// in your source and update them manually.

Comment: Is there a common directory/file where can I locate this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are a quite few things that could cause this, so there are lots of things you can try - I've listed as many I can think of below. You have already done some, but I'm including them here for completeness, in case someone else is searching with the same issue.

---

**1. Set WP_CONTENT_URL in wp-config.php**

Your `WP_CONTENT_URL` might be using HTTPS. As the issue is with including your theme files, this is the first thing I'd suggest checking out.

Try adding this to wp-config.php to force the website to use HTTP when including from the wp-content folder:

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://www.www.example.com/wp-content' );
```

---

**2. Set WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL in wp-config.php**

Set the `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` in wp-config.php to use HTTP. ***This will override whatever was set in the WP Settings***.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://www.example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.example.com');
```

You can also confirm what the values are in the database by querying the wp_options table and look for siteurl and home values, as you have already tried.

---

**3. Redirect HTTPS to HTTP in .htaccess**

I know you have this done already, but you could try it by checking if HTTPS `on` rather than HTTP is `not off`. (Also note - **302** redirect because this is not permanent!)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302,NE]
```

---

**4. Hard-coded URLs the WP database**

WP writes the full URL to the database, so there could be instances of urls using HTTPS in the db. You could check each table directly in the database, but I find the plugin "Better Search Replace" quicker and easier to use. You can do a "dry run" to search for instances of "https://www.example.com". If it finds any, you can use the plugin to replace them all (but as always, make sure you do a db backup first before making any changes directly to your db!!)

[Better Search Replace plugin on wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/)

---

**5. Plugins**

Some plugins might be trying to force SSL. There are the obvious ones like Really Simple SSL, but other plugins can also do this, such as security & optimisation plugins - I know iThemes Security does.

If all else fails, try disabling the plugins to check.

---

**6. Hardcoded URLs in theme files or plugin files**

It is unlikely with commercial themes & plugins, but it is possible that HTTPS is hard-coded into the theme files. Do a full search or try disabling the plugins and changing the theme to a default WP theme to check.

---

**7. Caching**

Your browser, server, caching plugins, minimizer plugins (for CSS & JS) might have HTTPS in the cache (Unlikely in your case, but I'll mention it anyway). Even other less obvious plugins can have caches too, such as gallery plugins.

Clear all your caches including your browser, turn off caching plugins, etc.

You could also try adding this try adding the following to wp-config.php

```
define( 'WP_CACHE', false );
```

---

**8. Admin**

Make sure you are not forcing SSL for the admin area - add/change the following line in wp-config.php

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);
```

---

I've run into this problem for similar reasons, and if the first 4 steps don't work I find it's usually a caching issue.

I hope that helps, there a lot of things you can try, and if that doesn't fix it I'm out of ideas!!

Comment: In my case it was the 'ithemes-security-pro' plugin that forced a https redirect.

Comment: I tried point 3 using the access but it's not working. I am getting "Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead"

Comment: @NarenVerma Yes, that's because you are now using HTTP which is insecure :)

Answer (score 3):

All the information was useful, but the location of the `FORCE_SSL_ADMIN` option was important (I initially placed it at the end of `wp-config.php` and it did not work for me):

#### Enable/Disable SSL Admin on WordPress website

You can do that by adding/changing this line to your `wp-config.php` file (located in your WP main directory):

- enable SSL for admin

```php
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

- disable SSL for admin

```php
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);
```

#### Add it before the line - *important* :

```php
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

After these changes, your website will work over SSL. Of course, if you want to disable SSL you need to revert changes.

Source:

https://www.pixelemu.com/documentation/wordpress-tutorials/how-to-enable-disable-ssl

Answer (score 1):

A couple more variables to check in wp-config.php would be:

```
define( 'FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true );

// WPEngine specific
define( 'WPE_FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true );
```

Comment: This answer appears to be specific to WP Engine, not to WordPress generally.

Comment: Updated the answer to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I changed `$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';` to `off` in `wp-config.php`