# Wordpress Http -> Https Bricked Site

Tags: wordpress

I just followed "Implementing HTTPS for Wordpress" here: https://make.wordpress.org/support/user-manual/web-publishing/https-for-wordpress/

So basically I added an s into the URLs under General Settings. And now my site is bricked and won't connect. I can't get back into the admin. Is there any way to undo this?

Comment: Have you setup your web server (apache/nginx/whatever) and any site config for https/port 443? You have two options. Go in database and set it back per answer below, and/or install a SSL certificate and setup your site/web server properly w/ ssl so it listens and answers for the given site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable HTTPS and redirect HTTPS to HTTP in Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62315483/how-to-disable-https-and-redirect-https-to-http-in-wordpress) - it is about redirecting from HTTPS to HTTP, but just just need to reverse those. As you can see there are many steps and pitfalls beyonds what that guide mentioned, so take a look and see what else you might need to do.

Comment: That other question is a little verbose but super helpful so I'm accepting it. Good to see what else I may encounter. I think I can solve this issue now I am just waiting for access to the hosting provider and then I will approve the answer once I confirm it worked for me. Thank you all for your help! This has been a fun one :P

Answer (score 1):

If that's all you had done, you can go into your Database (via PHPMyAdmin or similar), open up the **`wp_options`** table (note, your prefix may be different than **`wp_`**, and change the `siteurl` and `home` option values to the one that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Via phpMyAdmin, goto your wordpress database, find `wp_options' table and change` wp_home`and`wp_homeurl` values back to what it was when working.

If you want to use SSL (https), you need to add an SSL certificate to your domain (can be done through most hosting backends), once you have the certificate, THEN you can do SSL (https).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I haven't connected to the db before so I don't know the connection string. Do they follow a standard format?

Comment: Best advice I can give is contact your host provider re: instructions to login to cpanel/phpmyadmin. Then follow the steps provided in the answer. It's pretty straight forward. Just be careful in there.